# Use variable number of columns/loop inside dplyr::summarize

Tags: r, dplyr

Currently I have the following in R.
Its simply giving me total number of males and females city-wise.

```
df %>%
    group_by(city) %>%
      dplyr::summarize(pct.female = sum(sbq04 == "female"), pct.male = sum(sbq04 == "male"))
```

Say I want to do the same summarization on a column `sbq05`
The said column contains around 18 distinct values `("first value", "second value", ....)`.
I can do something similar to what I did above like this:

```
df %>%
    group_by(city) %>%
      dplyr::summarize(pct.firstvalue = sum(sbq05 == "first value"), pct.secondvalue = sum(sbq05 == "second value"), ....)
```

However I would have to explicitly type out all the 18 values. Is there any shorter way.

I was thinking of getting all the distinct values of my column in a vector. And then loop inside summarize applying sum on each distinct value.
I am very new to R so i dont know if that is technically possible, or if there is any better way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `table(df$city, df$sbq05)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add your additional column as a grouping variable and get the number of rows in each group. You can do this more easily with the convenience function `count` in `dplyr` as well. If you then want to have one row per manufacturer, you can `spread` the values out. Here is an example with the built in `mpg` dataset:

```r
library(tidyverse)
mpg %>%
  count(manufacturer, cyl) %>%
  spread(cyl, n)
#> # A tibble: 15 x 5
#>    manufacturer   `4`   `5`   `6`   `8`
#>    <chr>        <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1 audi             8    NA     9     1
#>  2 chevrolet        2    NA     3    14
#>  3 dodge            1    NA    15    21
#>  4 ford            NA    NA    10    15
#>  5 honda            9    NA    NA    NA
#>  6 hyundai          8    NA     6    NA
#>  7 jeep            NA    NA     3     5
#>  8 land rover      NA    NA    NA     4
#>  9 lincoln         NA    NA    NA     3
#> 10 mercury         NA    NA     2     2
#> 11 nissan           4    NA     8     1
#> 12 pontiac         NA    NA     4     1
#> 13 subaru          14    NA    NA    NA
#> 14 toyota          18    NA    13     3
#> 15 volkswagen      17     4     6    NA
```

Created on 2018-08-02 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).